# Compute characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, definite-integrals, characteristic-functions

I have to compute the characteristic function of a random variable with density
$$
f(y) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp{\left( -\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t} \right)} p e^{-pt} \, \text{d} t
$$
so I get the following integral:
$$
\varphi_{p,x}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\xi y} \,\text{d} y \left[ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp{\left( -\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t} \right)} p e^{-pt} \, \text{d} t \right]
\overbrace{=}^{\text{Fubini}} \int_0^{+\infty} p e^{-pt} \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\xi y} \frac{\exp{\left( -\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t} \right)}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \, \text{d} y \right] \, \text{d} t,
$$

but I have no idea how to continue this exercise.

There is a common strategy to break this kind of integrals?

Comment: $f(y)$ seems to be simple or am I mistaken ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I can't see how it can be a simple function but maybe I'm mistaken

Comment: Note that the inner integral is the characteristic function of $\mathcal{N}(x, t)$. You can plug in the result for that and the integral should become simpler to deal with.

Comment: I can answer for $f(y)$, that's all.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thank you so much! That solved my problem!

Comment: Using Glasser's master theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem), $f(y)$ can be obtained in a closed form: 
$$f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp{\left( -\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t} \right)} p e^{-pt} \, \text{d} t=\sqrt{\frac p2}e^{-\sqrt{2p}\,|x-y|}$$